# How can it be shown that $\vec{w} + \vec{v}$ is either an eigenvector of a symmetric matrix or equal to the zero-vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How can it be shown that $\vec{w} + \vec{v}$ is either an eigenvector of H or equal to the zero-vector? I'm not sure how to approach this.

Here are the details given:
[image: details given]

I is a 3x3 identity matrix.

P is an orthogonal matrix consisting of eigenvectors.

H is a symmetric matrix.

This relationship should be valid for arbitrary n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$
v + w = v + Hv = (I + H)v
$$
Note that $H$ and $(I + H)$ have the same eigenvectors.  So, it suffices to show that $(I+H)v$ is either the zero vector or an eigenvector of $(I+H)$.

In order to show that this is the case, show first that $(I+H)^2 = 2(I+H)$.

---

Proof that $(I+H)^2=2(I+H)$:

Note that
$$
(I+H)^2 =
[P(I+D_H)P^{-1}]^2=
P(I+D_H)^2P^{-1}
$$
Now, show that $(I+D_H)^2=2(I+D_H)$. From there,
$$
P[2(I+D_H)]P^{-1}=
2(I + PD_HP^{-1})=
2(I+H)
$$

Comment: hmm not quite sure that I follow.
Ok so on the first line we are basically saying everything togheter is an eigenvector (which was somewhat given allready).
And that if you add 1 to every element on the main diagonal of a matrix H we don't change it's eigenvectors.
On the last line you are basically saying that $I^2 = -H^2$.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying in the beginning.  I am saying that adding $I$ doesn't change the eigenvectors.  I am not saying that $I^2 = H^2$.

Comment: ok not exactly bulls eye there heh, need to dive a bit real deep into this, thx though